# Display TableviewCell inside Collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i Have Set a Tableview inside Cell in Used Collectionview 
When i reload a collection inside tableview cell Not Display a Proper Image Inside Imageview

i Have attech Screenshot For Tableview Cell

[image]

Any solution ?? Suggestion me .

Comment: What is mean by proper

Comment: Show as your code